# MSSQL the same query runs slow then fast

Tags: sql-server, database, performance

I am using MSSQL2008. The query runs mostly slow(>12h) but in certain time of day, the same data, it runs fast(<2min). No locked tables .

Observation is that query runs very slow with LEFT OUTER JOIN of table variable, at the end there might be over 5mil records to be processed and inserted to another table variable.

I checked tempdb setting - it is set up to 1024,unlimited. Where can be the catch ?

I've tried to reduce the results set records count(those 5mil records) and it helps, so it looks that it has problem with some DB resources, CPU is ok, memory on the server is ok too, other applications which uses the same DB runs smoothly.
What more, the same query, the same data, runs time to time fast (<2min).

The query is not written by me, so I can't change it to keep expected results at the end therefore I need to figure out what is causing that the query, which runs in memory, runs so slow and time to time it runs fast.

For better image I am attaching example of the query looks like.

```
DECLARE @table_variable TABLE(
x
y
y
)

INSERT INTO @table_variable (this is fast always)
SELECT 
.
.
FROM DB_table

INSERT INTO another_table_variable
SELECT (this stm runs ages, but time to time it retrieve data in 2min)
DISTINCT 
coalesce(A1.x, A2.y),
coalesce(A1.xx, A2.yy),
coalesce(A1.xxx, A2.yyy),
coalesce(A1.xxxx, A2.yyyy)
FROM transactions tr
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table_variable A1  ON (condition tr.u = A1.u )
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table_variable A2  ON (condition tr.u = A2.uu )
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table_variable A3  ON (condition tr.u = A3.uuu )
```

I don't know if the example is sufficient to any ideas but thx for any of them.

Comment: I advise against a table variable. On 2008, a table variable is expected to contain 1 row, not 5 million. The query plan just won't be designed to handle the volume of data you're passing.

Comment: You need to take many measurements. Are the row counts the same? What's going on in the database? use `sp_whoisactive` to monitor it. Are you saying `@table_variable` could have millions of records? Last time I checked, statistics are not kept on table variables, so try a real table instead.

Comment: Change the table variable to a temp table with a primary key on the column you're joining with, and you should see dramatic improvements.

Comment: thx. I will try temp table. I thought that it is matter of any DB property which I can set to higher value and the stm will magically run faster .

Comment: right, but I am using function :( so I can't use temp tables inside. Still I am wondering why the query runs fast and then slowly.